# Saturation of an ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given a graded ideal $I$ and the polynomial ring $K[X_1,...X_n], K$ a field, I am trying to understand the saturation ideal $\tilde I$ of $I$ defined by the quotient ideal:
$$I:m^{\infty} := \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I:m^k,$$ whereby $m = (X_1,...,X_n)$ is the maximal ideal in the polynomial ring. Can you provide a simple example of $I$ and $\tilde I$ including a geometrical interpretation of $\tilde I$ (for example it's zero locus) and it's relationship to the initial ideal $I$ ? Thanks.

Comment: For a simple example, take $k[x,y]$ and the ideal $I=(x^2,xy)$. Then its saturation is the principal ideal $(x)$. Set theoretically they define the same set.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you elaborate in explaining the result ? What I find is the following: the maximal ideal in the example is $m=(x,y).$ Also, $m^2 = (x^2,xy,x^2),m^3 = (x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3 )...$ It follows, $...\subseteq m^3 \subseteq m^2 \subseteq m$ while at the same time $I:m \subseteq I:m^2 \subseteq I:m^3...$ The polynomial ring being Noetherien, it follows that there must be an index $s,$ with $I:m^{\infty} = I:m^s.$ How do I go from here to prove your result that the saturation is $(x) ?$

Comment: Show that $(I:m)=(x)$ and $((x):m^n)=(x)$.

Comment: I do not understand that.

Comment: Why $((x):m^n)$ and not rather $(I:m^n)$ ?

Comment: Is in general $(I:m):m = I:m^2$ ?